# Extract xmin/max, ymin/max for a tile from Mapbox API

Tags: mapbox, extents, api, extract

I am trying to harness the power of the Mapbox API (https://docs.mapbox.com/api/maps/raster-tiles/) to download some tiles. Easy enough.

I also though need to download some metadata about these tiles, namely - the coordinates of the four corners of each tile, in order to be able to place it in space.

According to the Mapbox API documentation, I've found the `Retrieve information about a single tileset job` request (https://docs.mapbox.com/api/maps/mapbox-tiling-service/), which returns, among other things, the `layer_stats.zooms.ymin, layer_stats.zooms.ymax, layer_stats.zooms.xmin, layer_stats.zooms.xmax` variables I am ultimately interested in.

In order to run this `Retrieve...` command I need the `tileset` and the `job_id`; the latter being the issue, as it is defined as `The publish job's unique identifier. This identifier is returned in the jobId field of a Publish a tileset response.`

I am having trouble understanding what this `job_id` is supposed to represent, as, per the definition, I infer that it can only be derived after a `Publish a tileset` command.

But I've never published any tilesets, I only wish to harvest them.

Can someone explain the proper usage of this command and its dependencies?

Or, if I am at a wrong path with my analysis of the API, can someone shed light on how this API if supposed to retrieve this kind of information?

Comment: The Mapbox API for the Raster Tile GET links to this OSM specification which describes how to convert ZXY tiles to lat/lon of the NW corner of the tile. It also describes how to find the arc size of a tile. This seems to be similar information you are looking for? https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Slippy_map_tilenames

Comment: Please [edit](https://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/423693/edit) your question and add info about which Mapbox API are you talking/asking.

Comment: Thank you both! I've edited my question to include the links to the api I am using (was unaware there is more than one mapbox api). @RomaH, I've used the link you've provided to convert the coordinate pairs I have (DD) to the tile number the API uses to extract the tile.  Every function is about converting long/lat to tile numbers or vice-versa. I want the four corners of each tile, not a single coordinate for the center of the tile. Still stuck on this btw. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Having a look at Mapbox docs I would say that  retrieving info you want is possible only for your own tilesets you created with the Mapbox Tiling Service: https://docs.mapbox.com/api/maps/mapbox-tiling-service/

Comment: My reading of the docs yielded the same result. Can anyone confirm? How incredibly futile would this be? Why would I only be allowed to extract the info on the tile I've uploaded. Chances are if I've uploaded it, I've taken it, in which case I have all the coordinate information already.

Comment: Try this library: https://github.com/mapbox/tilebelt. There is a method `.tileToBBOX` which seems to do what you want.

Comment: Thank you @TomazicM, will try and return a reply!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With great thanks to @TomazicM, who provided the much needed js library (Mapbox tilebelt). I used the following commands the install the library:

```
#1. make sure you dont have any npm or nodejs. If you do, uninstall everything with:
sudo apt-get remove nodejs
sudo apt-get remove npm

#2. Then go to /etc/apt/sources.list.d and remove any node list if you have.
#3. Then do a:

sudo apt-get update

#4. check for any files somewhere
which nodejs
which npm
which node

#5. nuclear delete
rm -rf usr/local/bin/npm


#6. Ready to install
#7 (?) if working in docker and container is not connecting to ubuntu archive:

echo "nameserver 8.8.8.8" | sudo tee /etc/resolv.conf > /dev/null

sudo apt-get update


#8. where to get the library from : https://github.com/mapbox/tilebelt

sudo apt install npm

#9. how to install nmp packafes with npm init - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50895493/solving-the-npm-warn-saveerror-enoent-no-such-file-or-directory-open-users

npm init

#10. fill in all the details (most importantly the link provided to the library on github)

#11. (?) install library globally (if you want)
sudo npm install mapbox/tilebelt -g

#12. install locally (I used local installations)
sudo npm install mapbox/tilebelt

#13. install benchmark lib
sudo npm install benchmark

#14 (?). set the env variable if necessary
#export NODE_PATH=$(npm root --quiet -g)
```

After that i have a js script that looks like this:

```
const args = process.argv;

//console.log(args);

var x = args[2];
var y = args[3];
var z = args[4];

var tilebelt = require('@mapbox/tilebelt');

var tile = [x,y,z] // x,y,z

console.log(tilebelt.tileToBBOX(tile));
```

which can be called like so `node getTileBBOX.js 10 15 8` and returns the bbox. The three arguments must be of the order x y z, where x = the x coordinate of the tile, as described in the slippy documentation (https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Slippy_map_tilenames), y = the y coordinate of the tile, z = the zoom level.

Answer (score 0):

I've got another solution that doesn't require all these installations, written in R:

```
#convert radians to degrees
rad2deg <- function(rad) {(rad * 180) / (pi)}

#convert tile numbers to coordiantes in degrees
num2deg <- function(xtile, ytile, zoom){
  n <- 2.0 ** zoom
  lon_deg <- xtile / n * 360.0 - 180.0
  lat_rad <- atan(sinh(pi * ( 1-2 * ytile / n)))
  lat_deg <- rad2deg(lat_rad)
  
  return(c(lat_deg, lon_deg))
}

#This returns the NW-corner of the square. 
#Use the function with xtile+1 and/or ytile+1 to get the other corners. 
#With xtile+0.5 & ytile+0.5 it will return the center of the tile. 

#use the num2deg function to get the four corners of the tile using +1 on tile numbers logic
getBBOX <- function(xtile, ytile, zoom, polygon_CW_CCW){
  
  NW_corner <- num2deg(xtile, ytile, zoom)
  NE_corner <- num2deg(xtile+1, ytile, zoom)
  SE_corner <- num2deg(xtile+1, ytile+1, zoom)
  SW_corner <- num2deg(xtile, ytile+1, zoom)
  
  #Clock-wise polygon defintion 
  bbox_tile_cw <- c(NW_corner, NE_corner, SE_corner, SW_corner)
  
  #Counter-clock-wise polygon definition
  bbox_tile_ccw <- c(NW_corner, SW_corner, SE_corner, NE_corner)
  
  if(polygon_CW_CCW == 'cw'){
    return(bbox_tile_cw)
  }
  
  if(polygon_CW_CCW == 'ccw'){
    return(bbox_tile_ccw)
  }
}

This would work the same from any tile service that uses the slippy tile standard.
```